# Signing APK file **/*.apk no matching file

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, apk, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build an Android pipeline in Azure Devops for my Xamarin application. This is what I have so far:

```
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

# Installing NuGet
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

# Restoring the solutions
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: 'Student360Mobile.Droid/Student360Mobile.Droid.csproj'

# Building the android app
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: 'Student360Mobile.Droid/Student360Mobile.Droid.csproj'
    configuration: 'Release'
    createAppPackage: true

# Signing the APK
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk' 
    apksign: true
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'debug.keystore'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: $(keystore.password)
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: $(keystore.key.alias)
    apksignerKeyPassword: $(keystore.key.password)
    apksignerArguments: --out $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/app.release.apk
    zipalign: true

# Publishing the APK so we can distribute
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

# Distributing the APK to app store
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'App Center'
    appSlug: 'Tyler-SIS-Mobile/Student360MobileAndroid'
    appFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app.release.apk'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'Automated build from App Center'
    destinationType: 'groups'
```

For some reason, I'm always getting this error: "No matching files were found with search pattern." I've tried a bunch of things:

- Setting the output directory of the XamarinAndroid@1 task to a specific directory and the appFile to that director followed by "/*.apk"
- Setting the output directory to $(build.artifactStagingDirectory) and the appFile to $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/*.apk
- Keeping the output directory clear and using the default directory for appFile, $(build.binariesDirectory)/bin/Release/*.apk
- Doing all of the above using '**/*.apk' for the appFile.

Every single one of these didn't work. It's almost like no APK is being generated. I believe I've configured the build appropriately, but I don't see in the log where that APK is being made. Granted, I also don't know if there would be a log for it. What gives?

Comment: I have discovered that I'm generating an .aab file, not an .apk. I have no idea why it's doing that considering I have createAppPackage set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csproj file was set to create an AAB file instead of an APK file. I overrode this behavior specifically for our Azure pipeline by adding the arg, -p:AndroidPackageFormat=apk, to the Xamarin Android build command.

Comment: Worked! facing the exactly same issue. thanks